# CSS Parents Sibling selector

Tags: css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="parent">
  <p class="tag">I live in Duckburg.</p>
</div>

<div class="color">
  <p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to apply a color to the second div, if the first div has a child.

I'm applying the following CSS.

```
.parent > .tag + .color{
  background-color: green;
}
```

Expecting it to select the parent of tag and then selecting the adjuscent color div and apply the background style. But it doesn't work. Can you please help.

Comment: no, there is no parent selector. You have to use Javascript for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I initially closed this question due to the requirement of a parent selector (which does not exist), but actually you don't need it.

As long as your empty `.parent` element is *entirely* empty, ie. no white space whatsoever, then you may be able to use the following:

```css
.parent:not(:empty) + .color {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p class="tag">I live in Duckburg.</p>
</div>

<div class="color">
  <p>I will be selected</p>
</div>

<div class="parent"></div>

<div class="color">
  <p>I will NOT be selected</p>
</div>
```